# Array formation and indexing are not allowed on .NET objects

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

I have a .NET dictionary in Matlab and I want to do this:

```
disp([moduleConfiguration.Parameters.Item('One'), ':', moduleConfiguration.Parameters.Item('Two')]);
```

but I'm getting this error message:

```
Array formation and indexing are not allowed on .NET objects.
```

I'm running out of ideas because this one is working:

```
disp(['One', ':', 'Two']);
```

Hope anyone could help me!

Thanks!

Comment: What is disp ? Consider using List<T> instead of array..

Comment: What is the result of  `moduleConfiguration.Parameters.Item('One')`?

Comment: It looks as if you're trying to build a character vector by concatenating things using square brackets, but the data being returned by the two `moduleConfiguration...` calls is not a MATLAB character vector. Probably you need to convert it to one first.

Comment: @SardarUsama contains e.g. System.String or  a double

Comment: @nekomatic Yes, that's the answer.. need to cast it to an char

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to convert it to an character! Thanks to @nekomatic

```
disp([char(moduleConfiguration.Parameters.Item('One')), ':', char(moduleConfiguration.Parameters.Item('Two'))]);
```